# Go code for BiqQuery load table of JSON files from Cloud Storage; auto-detect schema

Tags: json, go, google-bigquery

I would like to load a table in BigQuery from json-formatted Google Cloud Storage files, and have the 'auto-detect schema' option as available in the BigQuery Console UI enabled.

I would like to do this in Go using the BigQuery package `cloud.google.com/go/bigquery`but cannot figure it out from the docs. Can someone provide a code sample? I don't want to use Python.

Comment: I don't know `Go`, but the flag is there in the API docs, as is an example of loading a file. So, you should be able to get going with that. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/blob/master/bigquery/file.go#L46

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reference. The FileConfig struct has to be set as an attribute of GCSReference:

```html
// Load JSON formatted files from
// Google Cloud Storage to BigQuery
// Auto-detect schema
func LoadTblJson(ctx context.Context, client *bigquery.Client,
 pth string, datasetName string, tableName string) {


 dataset := client.Dataset(datasetName)
 gcsRef := bigquery.NewGCSReference(pth)

 // set FileConfig attribute of GCSReference struct
 var dataFormat bigquery.DataFormat
 dataFormat = "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON"
 flConfig := bigquery.FileConfig{SourceFormat: dataFormat,
  AutoDetect: true, Schema: nil}
 gcsRef.FileConfig = flConfig


 loader := dataset.Table(tableName).LoaderFrom(gcsRef)
 loader.CreateDisposition = bigquery.CreateIfNeeded
 loader.WriteDisposition = bigquery.WriteEmpty

 job, err := loader.Run(ctx)
 if err != nil {
  //Handle
 }
 status, err := job.Wait(ctx)
 if err != nil {
  // Handle
 }
 if status.Err() != nil {
  //Handle
 }



}
```